# What could cause a freezing socket between C++ and Java?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, messaging, file-transfer

I am trying to implement socket connection between C++ client and Java server.
It must be cappable of sending files, and image file for every iteration as well as text.
The C++ client is a dll.
I am suffering to understand where is the problem. If both applications are sockets - locked by default, yet the client seems to "overtake" the server.
For this reason server is sending request for data first, than just next - data should come back.
I thought that should work, but not.
Also setting some sleep between messages in the server improves functionality, but with or withouth sleep - Beep() server freezes, it seems it is working just slightly slower than client - it seems there is no synchronization.
Plese help! Can you can give any valuable advice?

Below are important parts of both applications:

C++ client

```
while (userInput.size() > 0)
{
    //some other lines
    const int64_t fileSize = GetFileSize(fName);
    int chunkSize = 1024
    char buff; 
    RecvBuffer(sock, &buff, 5, 5);      // 5 chars message length "A\r\n", another 5 to send at once ?
    cout << "rcvd: " << buff<< endl;    //Printing "rcvd: A" - it was sent from Java "A\r\n"    
    SendPackage(sock, fName, chunkSize, ks);
    cout << "sent: " << endl;       //This "sent: " is "walking back before rcvd: A" with different speed every time the program is started
    //Beep(8000, 100);
}



int RecvBuffer(SOCKET s, char* buffer, int bufferSize, int chunkSize) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < bufferSize) {
        const int l = recv(s, &buffer[i], __min(chunkSize, bufferSize - i), 0);
        if (l < 0) { return l; } // this is an error
        i += l;
    }
    return i;
}



int64_t SendPackage(SOCKET s, const std::string fileName, int chunkSize,std::string header) {
   
    int64_t fileSize = GetFileSize(fileName);
    if (fileSize < 0) { return -1; } 
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (file.fail()) { return -1; } 
    if (send(s, header.c_str(), header.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) { return -2; }
    std::vector<char> buffer(chunkSize);
    bool errored = false;
    int64_t bytes_sent = 0;

    while (fileSize > 0) {
        //Beep(0, 2000);//Any delay here also helps
        int ssize = static_cast<int>(std::min<int64_t>(fileSize, chunkSize));
        if (!file.read(buffer.data(), ssize)) { errored = true;  std::cout << "err!!!" << std::endl;break; }
        if (!SendBuffer(s, buffer.data(), ssize)) { errored = true; std::cout << "err!!!" << std::endl; break; }
        fileSize -= ssize;
    }
    file.close();

    if (errored) {
        std::cout << "err" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }
    return bytes_sent;
}



BOOL SendBuffer(SOCKET s, const char* buffer, int bufferSize) {
    
    if (bufferSize > 0)
    {   
        int numSent = send(s, buffer, bufferSize, 0/*MSG_DONTROUTE*/);
        if (numSent < 0) {
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Java Server

```java
while(!Message.equals("command_Exit"))
{   
    ps.println("A\r\n");
    long filesize = 0;
    
    String inputStr = br.readLine();
    filesize = pD.getFileSize(inputStr);
    dis = new DataInputStream(bis);        //bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);//is = s.getInputStream();//s - socket
    int pos = 0;
    
    if (filesize > 0)
    {  
       byte[] totalbytes = new byte[(int)filesize];   
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
       do
       {   
           int chunkSize = (int) Math.min(filesize, (long) bytes.length);
           dis.readFully(bytes, 0, chunkSize);
           int x = 0;
           while(x<chunkSize)
           {
            totalbytes[pos] = bytes[x];
           x++;
           pos++;
           }
           filesize -= chunkSize;
       }
       while (filesize > 0);
       ByteArrayInputStream input_stream= new ByteArrayInputStream(totalbytes);
       BufferedImage final_buffered_image = ImageIO.read(input_stream);
       System.out.println(final_buffered_image);
    }
    dis=null;
}
```

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you very much for the time spent!

Comment: You should check the return value of the functions `RecvBuffer` and `SendPackage`. Also, your code doesn't seem to be a [mre] - especially Java code. If you are facing issues. I recommend to first check one way communication from client to server and resolve all issues you face there. Once done, then check communication from server to client.

Comment: It looks like you may have combined `BufferedReader` with `BufferedInputStream` so are skipping over various chunks of the input and converted image bytes to characters on the way => hence not working.

Comment: I have followed the perscription of @kiner_shah and work continues with another topic. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DuncG finally if everything is done i will post it back here. Yes they really mixed everything. Reading from one doesn't affect the other. Thank you very much!